# How to validate if a process under test is running when running load test using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am establishing websocket connection  using Websocket sampler to  the service and sending messages,I have to check whether the service running or crashed during load testing using JMeter

I have gone through OS sampler,but didn't get the proper articles on how to check the process running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectation is that if the service has crashed it will not be able to respond properly therefore JMeter will automatically mark your WebSocket Samplers as failed. You can also set a reasonable timeouts for the [WebSocket Samplers](https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers#samplers) so JMeter would not wait for the connection/response forever.

[image]

You can also add a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to check whether your server returns expected data, absence of errors, etc.

With regards to checking the process it can be done either using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) in combination with [Powershell Remoting](https://blog.netspi.com/powershell-remoting-cheatsheet/) if your server runs on Windows and [SSH Command Sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) if it runs Linux or Unix-like system.

The commands you need to invoke are [tasklist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist) for Windows and [ps](http://www.linfo.org/ps.html) for Unix and derivatives. Check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/) article for above Samplers configuration examples for different operating systems.

Comment: I have to check another process related to service ,so I was looking for it

Comment: I was able to get expected results using OS sampler,I wrote a batch file to check if process is running and included it in OS Sampler